# How to reset non-zero constant to 0 on .wav file using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I loaded .wav file using wavread. My speech signal starts with some nonzero constant value, such as 1, before the actual speech starts. I am trying to reset these values to 0 up to the point where the values in my array y begin to vary. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the value is *constant**, you can do:

```
y = wavread(filename)
y(1:find(y~=y(1))-1) = 0;
```

To illustrate:

```
y =
     1     1     1     6     5     9     9     3     1     2    
y(1:find(y~=y(1))-1) = 0
y =
     0     0     0     6     5     9     9     3     1     2
```

*If it's not absolutely constant (very small variances), you can do:

```
y(1:find(abs(y-y(1))>1e-6)-1) = 0
```

Comment: Good one, what is the role of `-1`? I couldn't get it.

Comment: @Kamtal: It finds the first value that's _not_ constant. Since that value must remain unchanged, only the values in front of it shall be set to zero, therefore `-1`. =)

Comment: @Robert P, nice. I think you better use the `first` property of the function `find`

Answer (score 0):

If your file is 1D you can try this,

```
y = wavread(filename);
y(cumsum(diff(y)) == 0 ) = 0;
y(1) = 0;
```